# Openoffice - "Cant read contents" exception while i am trying to insert document into an .ott file.

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am trying to insert the contents of a word document into a placeholder in a .ott file. This later gets saved as a pdf file. I am getting a exception with the following stack trace.

```
Caused by: com.sun.star.lang.WrappedTargetException: Can't read contents!
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:177)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:143)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:335)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:304)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:91)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:639)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:151)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:133)
```

The piece of code which creates the problems is as follows.

```
OOoInputStream inputStream = new OOoInputStream(docByteArray);

                embedDocPropValues[1] = new PropertyValue();
                embedDocPropValues[1].Name = "InputStream";
                embedDocPropValues[1].Value = inputStream; 
                //xcomponent = xcomponentloader.loadComponentFromURL("private:stream", "_blank", 0, props);

                iDocumentInsertable.insertDocumentFromURL("private:stream", embedDocPropValues);
```

wherein the class OOoInputStream has the following declaration.

```
public class OOoInputStream extends ByteArrayInputStream implements XInputStream, XSeekable
```

The implementation works file when a *.doc is tried to be inserted into the template, but i get the error when use a *.docx file.

i am currently using OpenOffice 3.3 and java 1.5.

Can anyone please help me out in resolving the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told by the Moderators and Admins from Open office to report the same as a bug for fix in future releases. They have tried the same but couldn't resolve the same either. So anyone facing similar such issues keep an eye on the future releases and latch on if the issue is resolved.

Comment: 2016 year. LibreOffice 5.2. Bug still exist.